# Angular 9 - Routes

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8, angular9

I'm very new at Angular 9.

These are my routes:

http://localhost:4200/pc_configuration

--> then go to login

http://localhost:4200/PC2/login

-- it works fine, but when I login, dashboard overwrite the id (PC2)

http://localhost:4200/dashboard/

-- it should be

http://localhost:4200/PC2/dashboard/

These are my Routes:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', children:[
        { path: '', redirectTo: 'pc_configuration', pathMatch:'full' },
        { path: 'pc_configuration', component: PcConfigComponent },
        { path: ':id', children:[
            { path: '', redirectTo:'login', pathMatch:'full'},
            { path: 'login', component: Login2Component },
            { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent},
        ]}  
    ]},
];
```

and this is my login method:

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

export class Login2Component {

    constructor(private route:Router){}

    onLogIn(){       

        this.route.navigateByUrl('/dashboard');

    }
}
```

What I did wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 options that I can think of.

1. Navigate to the full route, including your parameter.
2. Navigate to the route relative to the current route

Either way, you will need to inject the current route, an instance of `ActivatedRoute`.

#### Navigate to the full route

You will need to get the current `id` param from the route

```js
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

export class Login2Component {

  constructor(private route:Router, private route: ActivatedRoute){}

  onLogIn() {       
    const id: string = this.route.snapshot.params.id;
    this.route.navigateByUrl(`/${id}/dashboard`);
  }
}
```

#### Navigate to the relative route

You can navigate to a sibling route using the `../{sibling}` pattern and specifying `relativeTo: this.route`.

```js
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

export class Login2Component {

  constructor(private route:Router, private route: ActivatedRoute){}

  onLogIn() {       
    this.route.navigate([`../dashboard`], {
      relativeTo: this.route
    });
  }
}
```

#### Which is better?

Even though option 2 looks cleaner, I personally prefer option 1. It means you can refactor your route hierarchy without worrying about breaking relative navigation. This is just my opinion though. Either option is technically acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

You need to navigate in relative to your current route. This is better so that you will not need to keep track of PC :id.

```
constructor(private router: Router,
            private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

....
this.router.navigate(['dashboard'], {relativeTo: this.route});
...
```